# how to access sqlite database from node-red node?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-red

I am creating a node-red API service that access SQLite database using SQLite node.
How to configure the database with SQLite node?

I have hard-coded db file in SQLite node.
What is the right way to develop a node-red API that access the SQLite database ?
I think I want to make the database filename configurable, so that it is fetched dynamically.

I am new to node-red programming.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the database you are accessing? None of the current SQLite nodes support dynamically changing the database file path.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the db path with the sqlite node. When I deploy the API, the database file and path may be different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes are only at deploy time not runtime then you can use Environment variables as described in the doc [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables)

If you replace the path to the DB in the config node with `${DB_PATH}` then Node-RED will replace this with the value of the `DB_PATH` environment variable at deploy time.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the documentation for creation configuration nodes?

https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/config-nodes

Comment: This is basically a link only and doesn't really help as creating config nodes is about developing new Node-RED nodes, the OP wants to know how to do this with existing nodes.